# How to get the remaining computational budget inside the transaction?

Tags: transactions, rust, performance

There is a function `sol_log_compute_units()` in the Solana [API](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/d9b0fc0e3eec67dfe4a97d9298b15969b2804fab/sdk/program/src/log.rs#L141) that *logs*  the remaining number of compute units. Is it possible to get this value *inside* the transaction. (i.e. something like `sol_get_compute_units() -> usize`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not currently a way to get compute units remaining outside of logging it within the program with `sol_log_compute_units()`